# Listar por DNI - Asp.net mvc 4 db Access

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, poo, ms-access

Estoy programando en ncapas, asp.net mvc 4 bd Access y lo que necesito es listar una data por su DNI que le envio.el DNI si llega pero no filtra. me sigue listando toda la info.
Este es mi codigo.

```
public List<TAsistenciaDTO> ObtenerAsistenciaxDNI(string dni)
        {
            List<TAsistenciaDTO> asistenciaList = new List<TAsistenciaDTO>();

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            using (OleDbConnection conn = ConexionDAL.ConexionACCESS())
            {
                var commandText = "Select * from TAsistencia";

                OleDbCommand comando = new OleDbCommand(commandText, conn);
                comando.Parameters.Add("@PerMarcacion", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = dni;

                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(comando);
                da.Fill(ds);
                conn.Close();
                DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
                foreach (DataRow rows in dt.Rows)
                {
                    TAsistenciaDTO product = new TAsistenciaDTO();
                    product.AsiFec = Convert.ToDateTime(rows["AsiFec"].ToString());
                    product.PerMarcacion = rows["PerMarcacion"].ToString();
                    asistenciaList.Add(product);
                }
                return asistenciaList;
            }
        }
```

Lo que no entiendo bien es esta linea de codigo `comando.Parameters.Add("@PerMarcacion", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = dni;`.

Tambien lo hice anidando el valor osea: `var commandText = "Select * from TAsistencia where PerMarcacion='"+ dni +"'";` pero me sale el siguiente error **No coinciden los tipos de datos en la expresion de criterios**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK... hay dos problemas a simple vista...

o a la query le falta la clausula where (que es lo que se ve en este momento) o cuando armas la query con el parametro, el DNI no es un string (probablemente sea un numero)...

```
var commandText = "Select * from TAsistencia WHERE PerMarcacion = ?";
OleDbCommand comando = new OleDbCommand(commandText, conn);
comando.Parameters.Add("@PerMarcacion", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = dni;
```

El parameter add vas a tener que revisarlo. Seguro no es un varchar.

de otra forma, elimina pasar el parametro de esa forma (no lo recomiendo) y concatenala de otra forma

```
var commandText = "Select * from TAsistencia WHERE PerMarcacion = " + dni;
```

Comment: Funciono Muchas Gracias @gbianchi